# Knockout.js : manually trigger computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a grid and a select control on the page. Choosing any select value triggers grid update. That updating is done using computed. Can I manually trigger grid to update, say, in situation when a new value is added to a grid?

```
 function vm(){
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.chosen_category = ko.observable("");

    self.pager = {
        page_namber : ko.observable(1),
        page_size : ko.observable(10)
    };

     self.sort = {
       field : ko.observable('name'),
       dist : ko.observable('asc')
     };
     // etc. 

     self.fetch = ko.computed(function(){
        $.ajax({
               url: '/api/items/',
               type: 'GET',
               data: ko.toJSON(self),
               contentType: 'application/json',
               success: self.items
          });
     }, self);


      self.add_item = function() {
        //here I want to update the grid
        self.fetch(); // not work
      };
 }
```

Sure I can move it to a separate function but I am looking for a cleaner solution.
Thanks!

**working version :**

```
          function vm() {
            var self = this;

            self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.chosen_category = ko.observable("test");

            self.pager = {
                page: ko.observable(1),
                size: ko.observable(10)
            };

            self.sort = {
                field: ko.observable('name'),
                dist: ko.observable('asc')
            };

            self.fetch = function () {
                var data = {
                    category: self.chosen_category(),
                    pager: ko.toJS(self.pager),
                    sort: ko.toJS(self.sort)
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/items/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: ko.toJSON(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: self.items
                });
            };

            self._auto_update = ko.computed(self.fetch).extend({ throttle: 1 }); ;

            self.add_item = function () {
                self.fetch();
            };
        }
```

Comment: You dont need to update it manually since items is a observableArray. But i'm not sure I like the way you are using computed observables

Comment: I think the idea of KnockOut is that you make things observable, not trigger it yourself. The fetch method should automatically be invoked by a change of the collection. I'm searching how, do you have a more complete example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is better to do this with `subscription` instead of `computed`. In that case you can define fetch function to use for both subscription and manual call:

```
function vm(){
  var self = this;

  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.chosen_category = ko.observable("");

  self.fetch = function(){   
    $.get('/api/items/' + self.chosen_category(), self.items);
  };

  self.chosen_category.subscribe(self.fetch);


  self.add_item = function() {
   //here I want to update the grid
   self.fetch(); 
  };
}
```

Also you can do the same with computed:

```
function vm(){
  var self = this;

  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.chosen_category = ko.observable("");

  self.fetch = function(){   
    $.get('/api/items/' + self.chosen_category(), self.items);
  };

  self.doStaff = ko.computed(self.fetch);


  self.add_item = function() {
   //here I want to update the grid
   self.fetch(); 
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes this solution works, but if I am going to have more fields in future to send to ther serverI have to add subscribe for every of them.

Comment: You can do the same with computed, in that case ko will automatically subscribe all observables used in a function.

Comment: @AndrewLuzkovky I would suggest doing this explicitly and not through computed. Also I think that's it's not the best idea to send the vm as the request - you should really have some other object to encapsulate the query. Moreover, returning JSON arrays from REST service is not safe: http://incompleteness.me/blog/2007/03/05/json-is-not-as-safe-as-people-think-it-is/